# Country-Currency MDX Mapping

Tags: ssas, mdx, powerpivot

I'm quite new to MDX and I'm facing an issue I'm unable to solve, even after reading documentations. I have a database that contains values from all countries in all possible currencies (like e.g. Netherlands in EUR, USD, CZK, HUF, Germany in all currencies, Czech Republic in all currencies, etc.).

Now, I would like to build an MDX query in which I define pairs of country-currency values to query for and avoid having all countries with all currencies in my PowerPivot table, e.g.

Netherlands - EUR

Czech Republic - CZK

Hungary - HUF

etc.

Is that somehow possible?

Thanks and all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going against the best practice, you can set that up in `MDX` using the concept of calculated member.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].Currency AS
CASE DimCountry.CountryName.CURRENTMEMBER
   WHEN DimCountry.CountryName.&[Netherlands] THEN "Euro"
   WHEN DimCountry.CountryName.&[Czech Republic] THEN "CZK"
   WHEN DimCountry.CountryName.&[Hungary] THEN "HUF"
END

SELECT 
    DimCountry.CountryName.MEMBERS ON ROWS,
    [Measures].Currency ON COLUMNS
FROM [YourCube]
```

The saner and better option would be add a "CurrencyOfCountry" column in your "Countries" table and populate the values there itself.

Comment: Agreed with the last option after code, since using CASE in MDX decreases performance. Creating `CurrencyOfCountry` property and showing it as a new measure is much better: `[DimCountry].[CountryName].CurrentMember.Properties( "CurrencyOfCountry" )`

Comment: @souravA I agree with Alex - I think for future reference it might be better to edit your answer with the CurrencyOfCountry first - and the CASE script as an aside?

Comment: I think that's a decent answer as it is. OP wanted to solve the issue using `MDX`, so I started with that. Since it is not a best practice, I mentioned that as a post script. Sometimes it is unfeasible to change the cube structure; so my answer more on that paradigm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments.